# How to deallocate texture from memory in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

I’d like to know how to deallocate memory from assets that I no longer need in a particular scene. Currently, our assets textures are staying in memory after we unload the asset in a scene.

```
<a-scene>
  <a-box src="texture.jpg"></a-box>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: The easiest way to dispose a texture is to grab an entity's material and call `material.map.dispose()`. For example, `this.el.getObject3D('mesh').material.map.dispose()`, until A-Frame can automatically handle it.

You can get the texture objects from `document.querySelector('a-scene').systems.material.textureCache` and run `.dispose()` on a texture.

Alternatively, I believe you can grab the texture from an entity via `document.querySelector('a-entity').components.material.material.map.dispose()`.

There is an issue filed to do this automatically: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/2166