# Virtual tour creased on third scene using A-frame

Tags: webpack, three.js, aframe, webvr

I'm making a virtual tour using A-frame in combination with Webpack with 10 different 360 images, with background sounds and voice overs in 2 different languages: Dutch and French.

When I'm walking around, I change everything the `src`-attribute of the `a-sky` tag and add and remove some elements that isn't needed on that scene.

When I'm going to the 3<sup>th</sup> room, the tour is creased and I got this error:

> **Uncaught TypeError:** Failed to execute `shaderSource` on `WebGLRenderingContext`: parameter 1 is not of type `WebGLShader`.
>
> ```
> at Ft (three.js:16069)
> at new Zt (three.js:16596)
> at Jt.acquireProgram (three.js:17019)
> at b (three.js:21105)
> at M (three.js:21264)
> at ae.renderBufferDirect (three.js:20243)
> at _ (three.js:21034)
> at ae.render (three.js:20771)
> at THREE.VREffect.render (VREffect.js:394)
> at HTMLElement.value (a-scene.js:475)
> ```

I'm thinking this is an issue with the memory of A-frame. Is there a way to dispose it? The answer in this question [How to mange memory used by A-Frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43940665/how-to-mange-memory-used-by-a-frame), I didn't know how to use it because it's using textures and materials what I'm not using.

Also if I'm using this line of code:

```js
let aframe = require('aframe');
```

I'm getting this error on the start of my tour.

> **Uncaught TypeError:** Cannot redefine property: `vrEnabled`
>
> ```
> at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
> at WebVRPolyfill.enablePolyfill (bundle.js:76211)
> at new WebVRPolyfill (bundle.js:76143)
> at Object.14../util.js (bundle.js:74118)
> at s (bundle.js:68513)
> at e (bundle.js:68513)
> at bundle.js:68513
> at i (bundle.js:68513)
> at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:68513)
> at Object.50 (bundle.js:76344)
> ```

Because of marketing reasons I couldn't show my complete code. You must do it with this pseudo code:

```js
'use strict';
let childeren;

function init() {
  //  1. Get all the data from an external file
  //  2. Get important elements of the scene
}

function render() {
  //  3. First remove all the childeren of the `childeren` variable
  //  4. Loop over an array from the loaded data and make a new node with 1 or 2 images 
  //     as child
  //  5. Add a click event listener to the node and execute `click` when triggered
  //  6. Add this node to the `childeren` variable
  //  7. Append the `childeren` variable as child of the `a-scene` tag.
  //  8. Change the `src`-attribute of the `a-sky` tag
  //  9. Change if different the `backgroundsound`s `src`-attribute
  // 10. Rotate the camera to the north of the image to avoid disorientation.
}

function click() {
  // 11. Depended of witch element is clicked:
  //      - Execute `render` again with other data 
  //      - Change the `voiceover` `src`-attribute
}

init();
render();
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene id="scene">
  <a-sky id="sky" src=""></a-sky>

  <a-entity id="variables"></a-entity>

  <a-sound id="voiceover" src="" autoplay="true"></a-sound>
  <a-sound id="backgroundsound" src="" autoplay="true" volume="0.5" loop="true"></a-sound>
  <a-sound id="effects" src="" autoplay="true" volume="0.5"></a-sound>

  <a-entity id="camera">
    <a-camera look-controls wasd-controls cursor="maxDistance: 30; fuse: true">
      <!-- Here stands a cursor -->
    </a-camera>
  </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Each node got a `data`-attribute to know what scene must been rendered or witch voice over must play.

Why stops my tour and throws this errors? Is there a way to solve this bugs? All help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427327/how-to-deallocate-texture-from-memory-in-a-frame/42427362#42427362 to dispose. `src` actually just maps to the material/texture components which you are using.